# Use of Sitecore databases in CD and CM environments

Tags: sitecore

Content Delivery server(CD) =  Website pointing to Web db

1. Does this server contain Master db?
2. What is the use of Master db in this server?

Content Management server (CM) Live environment :-

- Website pointing to Master db
- Sitecore site pointing to Master db

3) Can we remove web db?

4) What is the use of web db?

Content Management server (CM) nomal :-

- Website pointing to Web db
- Sitecore site pointing to Master db

5) If the content editor edits the website using sc_edit then web db is updated or master db?

6) Do we need web db in this server?

7) Publishing on CM will publish the data of Master in CM to Web in CD?

8) How does the publishing mechanism know that the DB to publish is on another server (CM->CD)?

Comment: notable question badge today with 2500 view not a single upvote :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No need for `master` database connection on CD server

2) No use for `master` database connection on CD server

3) No, you cannot remove. CM box must have `web` database defined. This database should be the same which is used on your CD servers. That's how content promotion is performed. You publish item from `master` database to `web` so in fact you're copying a particular version of that item from `master` database to `web`.

4) See `3)` plus if you're using Solr (instead of Lucene) for indexing, your CM box should do the indexing of both master and web indexes.

5) `master`

6) Same as `3)`

7) No. Will publish from CM `master` database to CM `web` database (which should be the same as CD `web` database). Unless you mess with your connection strings badly.

8) It doesn't know that. It's SQL database. It doesn't care who uses that database. You are connected to the same database from CM and (possibly multiple) CD boxes. CM writes, CD boxes read. That's it.

To make things more clearer, check chapter `3.2 Isolating the CM and CD Environments` of [Sitecore CMS Scaling Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/scaling_guide_sc70_a4.pdf). It's for Sitecore 7 but it's similar in Sitecore 8+.

Sample multi-instance environment (image from Scaling Guide above): [image]

Comment: So CD is a server without any db. CD's db resides in CM, correct?

Comment: Well based on this link there seems to be dbs, in each server (CM & CD) https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/database_connection_strings_for_configuring_servers

Comment: No. CD server has access to `core` and `web` database. But the content is not created on CD servers. Content is created on CM server in `master` database and then copied to `web` database (which is used by both CM and CD box). See diagram above. One `Web` database used by both CM and CD box.

Comment: The diagram is very helpful. I thought the dbs were residing in CM server and also in CD server. But from the diagram I see that dbs are shared amond CD and CM. So dbs could be residing in its own server ( not physically residing in CD/CM) . Still one question remain, the url I gave gives the impression that there are separate dbs in each CD and CM, am I reading the document wrong?  https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/database_connection_strings_for_configuring_servers

Comment: Yes, you read it wrong. It only says that you should disable/enable particular connection strings. See the sentence above the table `When you configure a Sitecore server, enable or disable the following connection strings:`. Also read notes below the table. 1 core, 1 master, 1 web database. CM uses all of them. CD doesn't need master database. That's it.